# Ternary Operator double quotes

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mapping, conditional-operator, double-quotes

Hello everyone im trying apply  this simple logic but. i get undefined elements in an array. İ know i can do it with filter but i wanna do it this way so whats the solution ?  What is the problem i am having ? Thank you in advance!

```
    const newArr = ["abc", 12, 43, 8, 9, 0, 15, 23]

const newww = newArr.map(n => {
    (typeof (n) === "string") ? {return n} : {return n.toString}
}
)
```

The logic in English is: İf the type of n is equals to string return n if not return empty string.

Comment: `return (typeof (n) === "string") ? n : n.toString` :) One-liner `const newww = newArr.map( n => (typeof n === "string") ? n : n.toString )`

Comment: unlike if statements, ternary operators return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things wrong here.

Tertiary operators are evaluated as expressions themselves. So a `return` in them is wrong.

Also, the `toString` is a function so it should be written as `toString()`.

You can change the code to this so that it'll work:

```
const newArr = ["abc", 12, 43, 8, 9, 0, 15, 23]

const newww = newArr.map(n => {
    return (typeof (n) === "string") ? n : n.toString();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the cause of your problem, but you should write your return statement as this instead:

```
const newww = newArr.map(n => {
    return (typeof (n) === "string") ? n : n.toString
})
```